# How to use the pairs function combined with layout in R?

Tags: r, layout

I am trying to add a simple legend to a customized pairs graph.

Here is the reproductible code (without my customized pairs function) :

```
layout(cbind(1,2),width=c(1,1))
layout.show(2)
pairs(USJudgeRatings)
```

Why is the pairs function "erasing" my layout information ?

Comment: The "why" is easy. Because `pairs` calls `layout` itself. But you'll have to provide a much more complete example if you want help getting whatever output you want.

Comment: ...before someone chides me I should say that I don't know for sure that `pairs` actually calls `layout` directly, it could be simply doing `par(mfrow = )`, but the effect would be the same: it defines it's own layout.

Comment: <chide @joran > it uses `par(mfrow = )` <end chide @joran>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A warning contained in the help for `layout` is

> These functions are totally incompatible with the other mechanisms for arranging plots on a device: par(mfrow), par(mfcol)

Unfortunately, `pairs` uses `mfrow` for arranging the plots.

Using the hints from [Duncan Murdoch and Uwe Ligges on R help](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2001-September/015379.html), you can set `oma` to a reasonable value to give you room for a legend on the side, eg

```
pairs(iris[1:4], main = "Anderson's Iris Data -- 3 species",
      pch = 21, bg = c("red", "green3", "blue")[iris$Species],
      oma=c(4,4,6,12))
# allow plotting of the legend outside the figure region 
# (ie within the space left by making the margins big)
par(xpd=TRUE)
legend(0.85, 0.7, as.vector(unique(iris$Species)),  
       fill=c("red", "green3", "blue"))
```

[image]

Comment: OK thank you for that.
So if I want to have a pairs-type plot and a legend side by side, do I have to rewrite completely the pairs function and make the calls to par(mfrow=) compatible with my layout ?

Comment: @Chapo, Have a look at [this R-help thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2001-September/015379.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try to adapt it for my use.

Comment: After playing for a while I realized that "main" is important to make the legend works.